# Weird Subversion issue - tree conflict upon checkout

Tags: eclipse, svn, rad, subversive

Me and my collegues are using a svn+ssh repo to host our eclipse project. My other collegues have been using this repo without issues for about three weeks now. We are using RAD (Rational Application Developer) with Subversive for Eclipse to manage the source code.

Today when I checked out the project from SVN, every single resource in the project  immediately got flagged as "changed" ( the arrow > appears in front of every resource ) without me touching a single file.

When I syncronize with the repository in the team view, every single resource is marked as conflicting, more specifically "Tree conflict". And this all happens without me changing anything in any file.

Override and update does not help, Mark as merged does not help. I tried reinstalling Subversion and that didn´t help either.

Any clues on what might be wrong?

For the time being I´m using TortoiseSVN, and it´s working without any issues. However I´d prefer to be able to use Subversion in Eclipse if possible.

All thoughts appriciated!

Comment: Are there files or directories in the repo with filenames differing only in their case?

Comment: From Eclipse, can you right-click on the “tree conflict” and see what file(s) it says are in the conflict posting? On a guess, perhaps a top-level directory was renamed or deleted somehow, and your entire tree is showing as a conflict?

Comment: @Rudi: I´ll have to check that. BRPocock, that´s another issue. When I right click and select Tree conflict I get "operation failed", seems to be some internal eclipse/RAD issue. If something had been deleted at the top level, I´m thinking that atleast some of my collegues should be experiencing the same issue? But I´m the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never managed to solve this issue. Ended up using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working with Tortoise you probably need to refresh your eclipse workspace. Click on the project and hit F5, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem were conflicting SVN-versions. I had to install a different (newer) svn-connector and it worked fine.